# How to trim a string of whitespace and nulls in swift?

Tags: swift

So this is my code. I get the print ever time.

> [display] Unknown font "IBM VGA"
>
> [display] "IBM VGA"
>
> [73, 66, 77, 32, 86, 71, 65, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Could it be an encoding issue? Any idea how to fix it?

```swift
        let infos = String(bytes: data[106..<127], encoding: .ascii) ?? ""

        if (sauce.dataType == 1 && (sauce.fileType == 0 || sauce.fileType == 1 || sauce.fileType == 2)) {
            switch infos.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) {
                case "IBM VGA":
                    sauce.font = ANSIView.Font.IBM_VGA
                default:
                    print("[display] Unknown font \"" + infos + "\"")
                    print("[display] \"" + infos.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) + "\"")
                    print(Array(infos.unicodeScalars).map { $0.value })
            }
        }
```

Updated with new debug output...

How to trim a string with nulls?

Comment: You should consider one of the `String init(cString:)` initializers.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the `CharacterSet` struct & declare a new constant type property:

```swift
extension CharacterSet {

    static let whitespacesNewlinesAndNulls = CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines.union(CharacterSet(["\0"]))

}
```

Then, to trim the null characters:

```swift
infos.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesNewlinesAndNulls)
```

That being said, using [`init(cString:encoding:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1642803-init) (like mentioned in the comments) would eliminate the need to trim the null characters yourself.

Comment: to use the cString initialiser OP would need to map from bytes `[UInt8]` to CChar array `[Int8]`

Comment: @LeoDabus Why? There is a "cString" initializer that takes an `UnsafePointer<UInt8>`.

Comment: @rmaddy Yeap. But you would need to omit the encoding parameter

Comment: @LeoDabus It assumes UTF-8 and since the code in the assumes ASCII, that would be fine.